# validating the Uploaded Image name in Image field of Content type

Tags: 7

I need to validate the Image Name uploaded via Image field in Content type.How can i validate the Image name.

Any Help is Appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID"){
        $form['#validate'][] = 'myvalidation_function';
    }
}

function myvalidation_function($form, &$form_state) {   
    $file_fid = $form['field_your_content_type_image_field']['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['#value'][fid];
    $file = file_load($file_fid);
    $file_name = explode( '.', $file->filename);    
    if($file_name[0] != $form['type']['#value']){
        drupal_set_message('your validation error');
    }
}
```

Hope this works. I have tested on my system :)

Comment: You can also use this on node_insert or node_update.
just take fid from $node object instead of $form['field_your_content_type_image_field']['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['#value'][fid];
and changes the hook accordinly

Comment: Thanks Deepak,
Can we rename the File name in the backend and store in Database

Comment: @prashanth That is another question and should be asked separately. I think this solution answers the original question you have asked; in that case you should mark it as accepted and open a separate question if you have more issues.